# How to convert then-catch to async-await if promise is returned inside a conditional statement?

Tags: express, mongoose, async-await

I am trying to migrate from then-catch to async-await.

Here is the then-catch code:

```
 Source.findOne({ name: req.sourceName })
        .then(sourceData => {
             
            //Some code------------------  
            
            if (oldArticles.length === 0) {
                
                //some code----------------
                
                return sourceData.save();
            }
            else {
                //Some code------------------

                return sourceData.save();
            }

        })
        .then(result => {

            //Some code to manipulate result----------
            
            res.json(updatedResult)
            
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })
```

I am not sure how to return the promise inside the conditional statement. Please let me know if more information is required.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
 try {
    const sourceData = await Source.findOne({ name: req.sourceName });
     if (oldArticles.length === 0) {
       //code
     } else {
       //code
     }
     const updatedResult = await sourceData.save();
     return res.json(updatedResult);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.json(err);
  }
```

Comment: ``updatedResult`` was obtained when some operations were carried on ``result`` as mentioned in my question. Your method will add a lot of redundant code. Isn't there any other way

Comment: Your comment does not make any sense. There is no redundant code in this answer. If is doing the exact same thing as your code contained in the question with the exception that some redundant code was removed (e.g. `return sourceData.save();`)

Comment: @Fabian Strathaus, I wrote the comment on her previous answer after that she edited her answer. This is the reason you are unable to get the context of my comment.

Comment: Ah, sorry about it. My bad!